# Using STD along with exceptions in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c++11, stl, android-ndk

I've found some materials on the Internet stating, that NDK r5 enabled using STL libraries, but under the condition, that exceptions weren't used. I've checked lately, that current version of NDK is r9b, but didn't found informations, whether one may now use exceptions along with STL or not. Is it now possible? And also, does NDK support C++11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Yes the NDK supports most of C++11, provided you're using gcc-4.7+ or clang.
- Exceptions is supported since NDK r5 if you use the `gabi++`, `stlport` or `gnustl` standard library. You need to explicitly enable it in Android.mk with:

  ```
  LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
  ```

You may get more information from `docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html` in your NDK install.

Comment: Cool! Can't wait to start a new project in Android :D

Comment: how can i enable it in Android studio with gradle build system?

Comment: @CLIFFORDPY inside the ndk tag you add `-fexceptions` to cppFlags like this:
`ndk {
            moduleName = 'native'
            toolchain = 'clang'
            stl        = 'gnustl_static' 
            cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11','-Wall', '-fexceptions', '-frtti'])
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'z', 'log'])
            abiFilters.addAll(["armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"])
        }`